# Call nft_transfer using contract name on NEAR blockchain?

Tags: rust, blockchain, nearprotocol, nft, near

I have a question about NFT usage in NEAR blockchain. For example I have NFT on some marketplace (let's name it contract `A`). I add another contract (let's name it contract `B`) to approvals list on my Token (using NEP-178 and Approvals). Now this contract `B` can call `nft_tansfer` on my token and transfer it to itself account `B`. Is there a way to create method so I call it on contract `B` that will transfer NFT from `B` to me? It looks like if I call `nft_transfer` it will not work because I am not the owner of NFT and I do not have approval right.

I mean that contract `B` is ready to transfer NFT back to me but it has to do it when I ask contract `B` for it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You get it right, there is no other way around it unless contract `A` has some bug or special implementation for "previous owners" or whatever.